# If complex matrix 2*2 has a real eigenvalue then matrix of its conjugate elements has a real eigenvalue too

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ $\in$ $\mathbb C^{2x2}$ has a **real** eigenvalue then  $\begin{pmatrix} \overline a& \overline b\\ \overline c&\overline d\end{pmatrix}$ $\in$ $\mathbb C^{2x2}$ (where $\overline a,\overline b,\overline c,\overline d$ are conjugates) has a **real** eigenvalue too.

I'm having problem to find a counterexample (I tried to prove, but haven't come to something essential).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\lambda$ be the real eigenvalue of $A$. Note that $Av = \lambda v$ implies $\overline A \overline v = \overline \lambda \overline v$. What is $\overline \lambda$?

Comment: Dont know why I was trying to prove this by its characteristic polynomial, thanks.

Comment: No problem! You can accept an answer by clicking on the button left to the answer.